# fatal: bad numeric config value 'true{/code}' for 'credential.usehttppath': invalid unit

Tags: django, python-3.x

Can anyone help me solve this error as while git using git clone I found this error. By mistake I added `true` now unable to solve this error.

Comment: Where did you add that? Please provide *context*...

Comment: You really need to post your code so people on this site can see where the mistake might be.